# How should I optimize and handle this timeout error I am getting in Left Rotation problem?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I wrote a code for the https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/array-left-rotation/problem?isFullScreen=true left rotation problem on hackrrank. It was working fine for some test cases but for the ones with higher values, it's showing timeout error.

> Terminated due to timeout :(

How should I optimize?

I tried to store the values each time in an array and then recalling that array again for the rotation operation. Is this where it's taking time?

```py
n = 5
d = 4
a = [1,2,3,4,5]

arr_list_traversals = []
count = 0
while d > 0:

    arr = []
    for index in range(len(a)):
        arr.append(0)
    for i in range(0, len(a)):
        if i == 0:
            arr[len(a)-1] = a[0]

        else:
            arr[i-1] = a[i]
    arr_list_traversals.append(arr)
    count += 1
    a = arr_list_traversals[count-1]
    d -= 1

print(arr)
```

I know there are so many related posts here on SO, but I want to know what's wrong with my code and how can I make it work?

Sorry if this seems repeated.

Answer (score 0):

Because your shifting array one at a time your solution is O(n*d) since d<=n it's basically O(n^2). You can shift array by d once thus having O(n) algorithm. You cut array like so.

```
left = a[d:]
right = a[:d]
for item in left+right:
    print(item, end=' ')
```

Edit:
If it's harder to understand array slices this is the same thing using for loop.

```
result = []
for i in range(d,len(a)):
    result.append(a[i])
for i in range(d):
    result.append(a[i])   

for item in result:
    print(item, end=' ')
```

Note: Because while loop that runs d times is removed now time complexity is reduced to O(N) from O(N*D)

Comment: Still getting the timeout message. I get that I have to make it optimal. I will try some other method that does not include looping through another array. Thanks.

Comment: If you remove while loop and use this code it should work. I actually submitted this code and it's accepted.